# jQuery blur function is called twice

Tags: jquery

```html
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 location_detail" style="clear:none !important;">
            <div class="col-xs-12 txt_selectd_location">Selected Locations
              <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right">Qty.</div>
            </div>
            <div id="changeCont" class="col-xs-12 pad0">
              <div class="col-xs-12 unallocate-amount">
                <div class="col-xs-8 pad0 bold">Unallocated</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right" id="unallocated-stcok-display">200</div>
                <input type="hidden" id="unallocated-stcok" value="200">
              </div>
                            <div class="location_row">
                <div class="city">
                  Ahmedabad                </div>
                                <div class="city_square square-left"></div>
                                <div class="city_square square-right"></div>
                                <input type="text" id="3" value="0" class="input-in-out share-stock">
              </div>
                            <div class="location_row">
                <div class="city">
                  Bangalore                </div>
                                <div class="city_square square-left"></div>
                                <div class="city_square square-right"></div>
                                <input type="text" id="2" value="0" class="input-in-out share-stock">
              </div>
                            <div class="location_row">
                <div class="city">
                  Chennai                </div>
                                <div class="city_square square-left"></div>
                                <input type="text" id="6" value="0" class="input-in-out share-stock">
              </div>
                            <div class="location_row">
                <div class="city">
                  Kolkata                </div>
                                <div class="city_square square-left"></div>
                                <div class="city_square square-right"></div>
                                <input type="text" id="16" value="0" class="input-in-out share-stock">
              </div>
                            <div class="location_row">
                <div class="city">
                  Kolkata                </div>
                                <div class="city_square square-left"></div>
                                <div class="city_square square-right"></div>
                                <input type="text" id="17" value="0" class="input-in-out share-stock">
              </div>
                            <div class="location_row">
                <div class="city">
                  Mumbai                </div>
                                <div class="city_square square-left"></div>
                                <div class="city_square square-right"></div>
                                <input type="text" id="4" value="0" class="input-in-out share-stock">
              </div>
                            <div class="location_row">
                <div class="city">
                  Pune                </div>
                                <div class="city_square square-left"></div>
                                <input type="text" id="5" value="0" class="input-in-out share-stock">
              </div>
                            <div class="location_row">
                <div class="city">
                  Vadodara                </div>
                                <div class="city_square square-right"></div>
                                <input type="text" id="22" value="0" class="input-in-out share-stock">
              </div>
                          </div>
          </div>
```

jQuery blur function calls twice. How to prevent blur function calling it from twice. I am calling blur function to calculate input given by users The input field were on a popup. When i enter some values to input field and click on 'Tab' i found that console print here two times. Every time I click tab it iterate event multiple times.

My code is:

```
jQuery(document).on('blur', 'input.share-stock', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('here');
});
```

Comment: Also show the HTML, please.

Comment: can you provide jsfoddle or plunker or modify your snippet to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I have created a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/70ttk7ky/1/, its working fine here, but when you load this fancybox content through ajax you will face the problem like me facing